# Preserve leading white space when using Ace.OLEDB to insert data to excel

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

As the title states, the leading/trailing white space was trimmed after inserting data into excel file through Ace.OLEDB. Is there anyway to work around it?
I want to insert some data into a excel file. The connection string is "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;;Readonly=0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0;'".  One column of the table is of type "MEMO", which I may add some text with leading/trailing white spaces, like " Hello ". But what I found is it become "Hello" after adding to the table.

Comment: You should try providing a more detailed explanation of exactly what you had, what you did and what happened.  Details matter.

Comment: Please add details about your actual query that inserts data into Excel. How are you storing the text in variables? This is important to answer your question.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I have a query to insert row in an excel sheet like described and for a column, the value inserted is 'bla bla bla '. As you can see, there is a leading white space at the end of the string. The row is perfectly inserted but now when I go into the excel file and look at the value of the corresponding cell, the leading white space as been removed. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this option in connection string:

`IMEX=1`

Comment: You cannot use "IMEX=1" when you insert row into excel sheet.